# postMessage - multiple postMessage events/functions/callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, postmessage

Looked at this Q & A, but it doesn't solve for my issue:
[PostMessage with multiple functions or custom callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479911/postmessage-with-multiple-functions-or-custom-callbacks)

I need to use postMessage on load and then another within a click event, and the receiver for both would be on the same page (parent).

Is there a method  to scope postMessage? or to send multiple postMessages? I can parse the message to trigger specific functions, but how to have multiple posts?

Thanks

Comment: You can add an identifier to your message. I've implemented such in a method which uses `postMessage` for cross-domain `localStorage`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10505907/938089?is-there-any-workaround-to-make-use-of-html5-localstorage-on-both-http-and-https) (full code included, go inspect it ;))

Comment: To send multiple `postMessage` you just call `postMessage` multiple times.  What's not working for you?  Please post your code.

Comment: @robertc - I have it fixed now, but the for some reason, initially, the second postMessage was not sending. All working now.

Comment: jason i have now your same problem. My listener is not catching my iframe postMessage because one is already being triggered. So how to u solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My postMessage:

```
    $.postMessage(
        'layerTitle|'+ layerTitle +'',
        '*',
        parent
      );
...
var getDocHeight = $(document).height();
     $.postMessage(
        'iframeHeight|'+ getDocHeight +'',
        '*',
        parent
      );
```

and my receive:

```
$.receiveMessage(
  function(e){
    var message = e.data.split('|');
    if(message[0] == "layerTitle"){
    $('#ui-dialog-title-loginDialog').empty().append(message[1]);
    }
    if(message[0] == "iframeHeight"){
        $('#loginLayer').attr('height', message[1]);
    }

  }
);
```

Comment: Don't use `e.data.split`, a RegEx or a substring. Otherwise, you will loose data when the message contains the pipe character.

Comment: @RobW - but I control what the message contains - we regularly use pipes for exactly this scenario, because they are not a common character across our work - other than a separator within a string.